# Recuperar uma imagem na Storage do firebase e exibir no app usando GLIDE

Tags: firebase, download

estou tentando recuperar uma imagem da *Storage* do *Firebase* usando o *Glide*, pesquisei em muitos locais, utilizei o código da maneira como eu andei vendo e no entanto não consegui recuperar de jeito nenhum a imagem.
Em anexo mostra como eu queria que ficasse, a primeira imagem mostra como deveria ser, essas imagens estão no próprio app, em seguida a próxima imagem mostra como está ficando, eu retirei a imagem do calendário para tentar recuperar pelo *firebase* porém não consegui. Segue abaixo o código e as imagens

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageView proximaAcao;
    private ImageView galeria;
    private ImageView calendario;
    private ImageView contatos;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    proximaAcao = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.proxima_acao_id);
    galeria = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.galeria_id);
    calendario = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.calendario_id);
    contatos = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.contatos_id);


    Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load("gs://doe-amor.appspot.com/calendario_app.png");
```

já coloquei as dependências corretas na grade e nada, alguém poderia me ajudar?

[image: como deveria ser]

[image: como está]

Answer (score 0):

Isso porque você está utilizando a URL incorreta. Com essa URL só você tem acesso à imagem.

Vá à [consola do Firebase](http://consol.firebase.google.com), e encontre a imagem no Storage e clique em "Generate Download URL", será gerado uma URL para download da imagem (começando por "https"). Utilize essa URL no Glide e sua imagem irá carregar sem nenhum problema.

Comment: Eu fiz isso, criei o link para download, coloquei la mas continua da mesma maneira! Na verdade eu já tinha feito, eu usei os dois links, tanto esse que eu coloquei quanto o link para download.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que você esqueceu de colocar a ImageView que você quer que apareça a imagem

```
Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load("gs://doe-amor.appspot.com/calendario_app.png").into(suaImageView);
```

Espero ter ajudado